# Emacs 'csharp-mode' Byte Compilation Error

Tags: c#, emacs, compilation, compiler-errors, elisp

When I attempt to byte compile [csharp-mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/csharp-mode.el) under Emacs 24.2.1, I am getting the following error:

```
csharp-mode.el:2028:1:Error: Symbol's value as variable is void: csharp-enum-decl-re
```

[This post](https://code.google.com/p/csharpmode/issues/detail?id=9) confirms this same compilation problem and offers the following remedy:

> I tried manually defining csharp-enum-decl-re by doing C-x C-e on the
>   defconst; this got it to compile.

This remedy worked for me as well! However, this remedy leaves me with a couple of questions:

1. Without pre-defining `csharp-enum-decl-re`, why does **csharp-mode.el** fail to byte-compile? (See the first link for the source code for **csharp-mode.el**.)
2. Without modifying **csharp-mode.el**, is there a better workaround for this compilation problem?
3. The error indicated at **line 2028** concerns the following definition. Where is the dependency on `csharp-enum-decl-re`?

```lisp
(defconst csharp-font-lock-keywords-2 (c-lang-const c-matchers-2 csharp)
  "Fast normal highlighting for C# mode.")
```

Comment: This bug [has been reported here](http://code.google.com/p/csharpmode/issues/detail?id=1).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge:

1. The file fails to byte-compile because a macro needs the value of a symbol that has not been defined.  This error slips to some programmers because they are developing with an emacs session where they have eval'ed some of the code they are writing.  A typical solution to the compilation error is to use `eval-and-compile` macro for those expressions needed to know at compile time.
2. Using `eval-buffer` before `byte-compile` is a workaround that saves you from modifying the source.  Writing a patch and sending it to the author is another option.
3. Code is relatively tricky because of it relies heavily in macros.  `c-lang-defconst` is suppose to define values for `c-matchers-1`, `c-matchers-2` and `c-matchers-3`, but for `c-matchers-2` the value of `csharp-enum-decl-re` is needed (see line 1304).  Note that the name of the symbols (c-matchers-*) are created by the `c-lang-defconst` macro itself.

Comment: Likely, `eval-and-compile` is needed in this case, because the variable seems to be used at runtime as well.

Comment: **juanleon** - I have successfully byte-compiled **csharp-mode.el** with the guidance that you have given in both parts of your answer. (I tested each approach independently after running Emacs with the `--no-init-file` option.) I have added a number **3.** item to my question...would you have any insight on why the particular definition at **line 2028** is throwing the compilation error? The dependence of `csharp-font-lock-keywords-2` on `csharp-enum-decl-re` is not clear to me.

Comment: Yes, your addition of item **3.** helps. `csharp-font-lock-keywords-2` depends on `c-matchers-2` (which is defined in **cc-fonts.el**). `c-matchers-2` in turn depends on `c-basic-matchers-after` (defined back in **csharp-mode.el**). And finally, `c-basic-matchers-after` references `csharp-enum-decl-re`.